# Linux Find to delete files in folders

Tags: find

the goal is to find directories with given name and delete all files inside them, keeping actual directories

```
find /home/www/sites/ -iname '_cache' -exec du -hs {} \;
```

this gives me a list of files with their size

```
204K    /home/www/sites/test.site.com/html/development/Temporary/_cache
904K    /home/www/sites/test.site2.com/html/development/Temporary/_cache
```

is it possible to achieve with Linux find command?

Comment: Can't you `rm -rf` the directory and recreate it, since you know the directory name?

Comment: I have a lot of folders with such name, will be very time consuming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct command to erase it

```
find . -iname '_cache' | xargs -I {} find {} -type f -maxdepth 1 -delete
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried something and it seems it is working, it is a similar solution which Alex posted here.

```
find . -iname '_cache' | xargs -I {} find {} -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec rm {} \;
```

It should delete only files which are found in _cache directory and only in this directory. It will not delete any files from subdirectories of _cache directory.

Of course try it before using and instead of rm, put there ls or something harmless.

Comment: actually doesn't :) 

rm: cannot remove `/home/www/sites/test.site.com/html/development/Temporary/_cache': Is a directory

Comment: It won't delete directories as there is missing -r option. It will delete only files, not a directories. I can look at it later and test it once more.

Comment: it didn't delete files as well, I checked

Comment: hmm, strange, I will have to check it out, thanks for comments

Comment: IMHO, it's dangerous to use such a command. I wonder what will happen with a file named "_cache *"

Comment: find . -iname '_cache*' | xargs -I {} ls {} ===> This gives ls: cannot access ./_cache *: No such file or directory

Comment: Eric what you mention I think can be fixed by adding -type d in the first find command, but I did not test it, just thought

Answer (score 1):

I haven't thoroughly tested this logic...but you could do something inside a loop like:

```
for findname in $(find /path/to/search -name '_pattern')
do
  find $findname -type f
done
```

So you get the list of files that match your search pattern, and then loop through each of those with a new search looking for files to delete.

The way that is written will give you a list of files, so you could redirect that to a file and then loop through that with an rm.  You could also append an exec to the find w/in the for loop.  I'd certainly recommend running as written first to test the logic and make sure the matches look good.

Comment: yes, I can do .sh script, but thought is it possible to achieve by one command (maybe using pipes)

Comment: You can do this on a single line using ;'s to separate the lines.

Comment: for findname in `find /path/to/search -name 'pattern'`; do find $findname -type f -delete; done

Comment: I can't get the formatting to show the backticks...but the grey portion has backticks on either side of it.  Also before adding the -delete I suggest running this without it to verify what it's going to delete.

Answer (score 0):

find has a -delete option.  This will delete any matches.

From the man page

> -delete
>
> ```
>           Delete files; true if removal succeeded.  If the removal failed,
>           an  error message is issued.  If -delete fails, find's exit stat-
>           us will be nonzero (when it eventually exits).  Use of  -delete
>           automatically turns on the -depth option.
>
>           Warnings:  Don't  forget that the find command line is evaluated
>           as an expression, so putting -delete first will make find try to
>           delete everything below the starting points you specified.  When
>           testing a find command line that you later intend  to  use  with
>           -delete,  you should explicitly specify -depth in order to avoid
>           later surprises.  Because -delete  implies  -depth,  you  cannot
>           usefully use -prune and -delete together.
> ```

Comment: this will delete the directory with name _cache, however I want to delete files within that directory keeping the actual directory

Comment: ah sorry mis-read your question.